# Sum :$1+ 1/2 +1/3 +1/4 + 1/6 +1/8 \cdots $ , terms are reciprocals of the positive integers whose prime factors are $2$'s and $3$'s.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

I tried to break the series into different parts by two different methods

1. In terms of even and odd (no specific series is obtained in even, only Geometric progression formula can be applied on odd series)
2. In terms that contain powers of $2$ only, terms with $3$ to $1$st power, $3$ to $2$nd power,.. and so on

More specific pattern is obtained in the second method but I can't solve it further.

Help me further with the second method or any other one.

Any method given is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the harmonic series $\sum_n\frac1n=1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots$? If so, it should be pretty obvious what $\sum_n\frac1{2n}$ is...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I don't get it... how is it useful in the above question with multiples of 3?

Comment: If you know what the result of $\sum_n\frac1{2n}$ is, yours will follow fairly trivially.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Please elaborate and solve

Comment: I'm certainly not going to just answer the question in the comments, but I've given the necessary information you need. I've asked if you're familiar with the harmonic series, to which you never responded. If you're not, you can look it up. You can [edit] the question with what you've found and see if you can deduce anything further from there.

Comment: @MeetPatel what Simply Beautiful Art is hinting at is to first look at the mentioned sum $\sum_n \frac{1}{2n}$ and it will shed some light on the entire problem

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I disagree with your approach. What you should be using is $ \sum \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: Yes I do know what the harmonic progression you mentioned was, but I do not understand how is it useful in the question as no harmonic progression is involved in this series...

Comment: @CalvinLin Ah, that is my bad then, I misunderstood the question. I read it as "has a prime factor of 2 or 3" instead of "only prime factors of 2 and 3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$ \sum_{x,y} \frac{ 1}{2^x 3^y } = \sum_x \frac{1}{2^x} \times \sum_y \frac{1}{3^y}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can take it from here... but can you please provide the proof of the above statement?

Comment: @MeetPatel It's actually a restatement of your approach 2 above. Can you write that up, and then compare?

Comment: May want to clear up the indices.

Comment: Okay got it... I shouldn't have missed it

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks. (For such obvious typos, IMO edit it directly, but I know that people can get testy with your stuff.)

Comment: No, I meant on the summations. $\sum_x$? $\sum_y$? May be a bit unclear here, especially since the sums run over different variables.